# Include Category Description in search result

Tags: categories

I have pulled Category Description data

```
<?php                   
        $taxonomies=  array('taxonomy'=>'area-type');
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomies,'orderby=id&hide_empty=0');
        $count = count($terms);
        if ($count > 0) {
                foreach ($terms as $term) {

                    $id =str_replace("#","",$term->slug);
                    $term_desc .= '<div id="nav_menu_desc_'. $id . '"class="section hidden formateIt">'. wpautop($term->description) .'</div>';    
                }                  
                    echo $term_desc ;   
        }   ?>
```

And did show hide on click on a Category plus added #categoryName in url so client feel that it's a different page.

Sorry for this i am fresher in wordpress. So now problem is that they need Category Detail page which i have display with show hide they want that in search result how can i achieve this

Page link e.g :  www.sitename.com/PageType

On Click of Category it's turn to www.sitename.com/PageType#CategoryName

Sorry i was not able to add Category in before page name and now they have added 50 pages and i have to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will match your question : [create a search page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page). To customize search results you have to add a file called `search.php` to your theme.

Comment: My problem is i want get www.sitename.com/PageType#CategoryName in search result which i have achieve with jquery